# how to clear the form data when we already set the value as given in program. By using the clear button

Tags: php

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="country">Country</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="country" placeholder="Enter Country" name="country" value="XXXXX" >
</div>

<div class="form-group">
      <label for="social">Social media</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="linkedin" placeholder="Enter url" value="http:\\www.google.co.in" name="url">
</div>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" name="reset" onclick="resetform(form); return false;">Clear</button>
```

Comment: I guess just `reset` button could do the needful, `js` is not required at all.

Comment: Yes, reset button do this there is no need of `js` script but there is function reset form is called on button reset click above code that's why i asking about.

Comment: @balaji, Just try to remove `onclick="resetform(form); return false;"` from your RESET button code

Comment: ya i tried but in the text box i have already given some value to it. by clicking reset button it will not cleared off

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery to clear all input from form/div tag like

`$('.form-group').find('input:text').val('');`

Answer (score 0):

Just the `reset` button should do the magic:

```
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
```

Update 1:

```
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" name="reset">Clear</button>
```

Comment: The user has already used `button type='reset'` so I guess it is not required again

Comment: @Ms.Nehal yup! Even that will work. Thanks!. Updated my answer.

Comment: good but I already mentioned that in the **comment** so I guess it was of no use now